# what's the error this program in mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
create table order
(
code int not null primary key,
client_code int,
suite_code int,
gallery_code int,
foreign key(client_code) references client(number),
foreign key(suite_code) references suite(number),
foreign key(gallery_code) references gallery(number)
);
```

Complains about an error in the SQL syntax near 'order'.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site hasn't been upgraded with the telepathy plugin...

Answer (score 2):

Change the name of your table from `order`, to something not reserved by mysql, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the SQL keyword `order` as a table name (`order by` is used for sorting result sets). You can change it to something else or you can name your table `orders`.

I actually prefer the latter myself since the table contains a multitude of orders rather than a single order, and it keeps your intent clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
create table `order`
```

Comment: The keyword order is reserved in mySQL and changing the syntax will not help the problem, just confuse it

Comment: @Ryan: That's not true though, is it? It will _solve_ the problem: fact. Whether it's wise to continue using keywords as field names when using backticks to delimit them is a valid question, but it doesn't change the fact that this answer _is_ a solution to the problem.

Comment: @yi_H What are you talking about? order is a reserved word in mySQL, when I first read the question I ran the query in phpMyAdmin with an error creating the table, changed the table name to my_order with the same code and it works, if that is not the problem then what do you think is?

Comment: @Ryan: What the hell are *you* talking about? See Tomalak's comment.

Comment: @yi_H OOPS! Sorry mate, was looking at the wrong profile name when I typed it, @Tomalak Geret'kal see my response above @hami this is a dangerous game using a reserved word, if you don't want to change it then go ahead and use any working code but I would recommend simply changing the table name

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it either, I just said it's doable.

Comment: @Ryan: Yes, and I said as much in my own answer. But pretending that this "will not help the problem" is flat-out lying.

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize that my previous comment was mis-worded now, my apologies for that. What I meant is that to change the syntax to force the query may make people think that using a reserved word is ok when really it is not, it can become confusing if the person has just starting with mySQL especially and mix up what is best practice and what isn't, I see this in my staff regularly (especially new grads) and it is hard to break these habits. Again sorry for the confusion in my earlier post :-)

Answer (score 0):

The word `order` is a MySQL keyword and, as such, there is an ambiguity in your SQL statement.

You should use backticks to delimit user-defined fields:

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
   `code`         INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   `client_code`  INT,
   `suite_code`   INT,
   `gallery_code` INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (`client_code`)  REFERENCES `client`  (`number`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`suite_code`)   REFERENCES `suite`   (`number`),
   FOREIGN KEY (`gallery_code`) REFERENCES `gallery` (`number`)
);
```

<sup>(I've also capitalised keywords to make your query vaguely legible.)</sup>

The field names and keywords can no longer be ambiguous. However, **I would *still* recommend against using keywords as field names**, as this is confusing and error-prone — if only to the human reader!